# Do dark Skylanders work with the light starter pack?

Tags: skylanders

My friend has bought the light Skylanders superchargers starter pack and has found a loose Kaos figure on Amazon from the dark pack. Would it work with her light starter pack?

Comment: Yes, it will work just fine.